# Bug in my C code to reverse words in a string

Tags: c, string, algorithm

I was practicing some programming problems and tried to code the popular "reverse words in a string" problem.

I tried to come up with my own code in C. I am able to partially get it right. That is, "hello world" becomes "world olleh". I am wondering what the bug is here. I think somewhere I am creating an off by 1 bug.

As much as possible, I wanted to do it without using library functions. I searched here for this problem & found many solutions, but I'd like to know why my solution doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char*, int);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char st[]= "hello world";
    int len = strlen(st);
    int i=0,j=0;

    reverse(st,len-1); // Reverse the entire string. hello world => dlrow olleh

    while(st[j]){ //Loop till end of the string
        if ( *(st+j) == ' ' || *(st+j) == '\0' ) { //if you hit a blank space or the end of the string
            reverse(st+i,j-1); // reverse the string starting at position i till position before the blank space i.e j-1
            i=++j; //new i & j are 1 position to the right of old j
        }
        else {
            j++; //if a chacacter is found, move to next position
        }               
    }       

    printf("%s",st);
    return 0;
}

void reverse(char *s, int n)
{
    char *end = s+n; //end is a pointer to an address which is n addresses from the starting address
    char tmp;
    while (end>s)  //perform swap
    {
        tmp = *end;
        *end = *s;
        *s = tmp;
        end--;
        s++;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

**UPDATE**: Based on @Daniel Fischer's answer, here is the correct implementation : http://ideone.com/TYw1k

Comment: Given that this is a learning exercise, have you logically tried tracing through the code and its effect (perhaps even with paper & pen)?  Or alternatively, have you tried using a debugger to trace through its actual runtime?

Comment: Yes I used a debugger. When j's value is 11, the loop terminates. The character at position 11 in the string is '\0'. I can sort of think what the problem is here. Will try out what I thought & will update the question.

Comment: Wait, are you reversing a string, and then reversing every word inside it? Shouldn't that give you the original string?

Comment: @Shahbaz it will give him the string with the words in reverse order.

Comment: @Shahbaz , no it would not give the original string. Consider this: `reverse("hello world")=> "dlrow olleh"`. `reverse("dlrow")=>"world"`. `reverse("olleh")=>"hello"`. So at the end "hello world" => "world hello".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that

```
while(st[j]){ //Loop till end of the string
    if ( *(st+j) == ' ' || *(st+j) == '\0' )
```

the `while` condition prevents the loop being entered at the end of the string, so the last word doesn't get reversed again.

You can either make it an infinite loop, and add an

```
if (st[j] == '\0') break;
```

after the reversing, or reverse the last word after the while loop was left.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Fischer , I now made a call to reverse after the loop terminates so that the last word is reversed. Now the words are reversed. After the loop terminates, i is at position just after a blank space & j is at the end of the string. I do a `reverse(st+i,j-i-1);` and the last word is reversed.

Comment: I am accepting this answer as I fixed my code using this tip :)

Answer (score 3):

You have an off by one error indeed: the call

```
reverse(st+i,j-1);
```

should be

```
reverse(st+i,j-i-1);
```

Your code passes `j-1` which is the length from the beginning of the string to the position of the last space; it should be the length of the last word, so you need to subtract the index of the first character (i.e. `i`).

You are also not reversing the last word (see [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11278724/335858) for the details on that).

Comment: I realized it, and changed j-1 to i-j-1. Lesson learnt - try code on paper before jumping to debugger! It had to be i-j-1 as I need to calculate i-j positions from the starting address.

Comment: There's also a simpler elegant solution without strlen and co. See my answer.

Comment: @RBK Debug print also helps: the fact that you are passing wrong length would have jumped at you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to reverse words in a string, not reverse the whole string and then rereverse single words. So, delete first reverse and then apply suggested changes above.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char*, int);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char st[]= "hello world";
  int i=0, j=0;

  while(st[j]){ //Loop till end of the string
    if ( st[j] == ' ') { //if you hit a blank space or the end of the string
      reverse(&st[i], j - i - 1); // reverse the string starting at position i till position before the blank space i.e j-1
      i = ++j; //new i & j are 1 position to the right of old j
    }
    else {
      j++; //if a chacacter is found, move to next position
    }               
  }
  reverse(&st[i], j - i - 1);


  printf("%s\n",st);
  return 0;
}

void reverse(char *s, int n)
{
  char *end = s + n; //end is a pointer to an address which is n addresses from the    starting address
  char tmp;

  while (end > s)  //perform swap
  {
    tmp = *end;
    *end = *s;
    *s = tmp;
    end--;
    s++;
  }
}
```

Take care when input string would be '\0' or something like ' Hello world'. Above code doesn't managed this kind of situations. Think about it!

Comment: I can't see how your code will work. I wanted "hello world" to become "world hello", not "dlrow olleh". Your code reversed individual words: http://ideone.com/edomq.
Also I don't see why you want to do &st[i]. `st+i` itself does it and looks more elegant.

Comment: Apps ok! I undestand hello world -> olleh dlrow! (Reverse words). Sorry!

Comment: Oh, ok cool. Check out the edit I made to my question. I have included a link with the implementation which works.

Comment: About &st[i] or st+i, I prefer &st[i], but it is only an habit. Sometimes is a bit confused to understand code that has pointer arithmetic. With &st[i], you know that you are dealing with pointer thanks to &.

Comment: Yes, &st[i] is more explicit and easier to understand. For an array, the name of the array gives the base address of the array i.e st is same as &st. And st+i is same as st[i]. I just use these implicit conventions.

Answer (score 0):

@RBK: You first take a string, reverse it, then based on specific words you again reverse them.
I followed a slightly different approach of doing this. I take the string then reverse if required otherwise i copy the same word as it is.

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    char *p,st[]= "hello world";
    char buf[12]={0};
    char fstr[12]={0};
    int i=0,j=0,k=0,l=0;

    for(p=st;*p!='\0';p++){

        //Get the Word
        buf[i++] = *p;

        //Parse the Word    
        if(*p == ' ' || *(p+1) == '\0'){

            buf[i]='\0';
            j=i-1;
            i=0;        //reset counter

            if(k){      //reverse word and copy

                while(j>=i){

                    fstr[l++]=buf[j--];

                }               

                k=0;        

            }
            else{       //copy same word

                while(i<=j){

                    fstr[l++]=buf[i++];                     

                }

                i=0;    //reset counter
                k=1;

            }

        }

    }   

    fstr[l]='\0';
    printf("%s\n",fstr);
    return 0;
}
```